# SDL Function for Loading PNGs

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm learning SDL 2.0 at the moment and I've seen this method for loading BMPs:

```
SDL_Texture* LoadImage(std::string file)
{
    SDL_Surface *loadedImage = nullptr;
    SDL_Texture *texture = nullptr;
    loadedImage = SDL_LoadBMP(file.c_str());

    if (loadedImage != nullptr)
    {
        texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedImage);
        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);
    } 
    else
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return texture;
}
```

How could I switch it up to load PNG files?

EDIT: Woops, forgot to add my method of loading PNGs.

```
SDL_Texture* grass_image = nullptr;
grass_image = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "res/grass.bmp");
SDL_Rect grass_rect;
    grass_rect.x = 0;
    grass_rect.y = 0;
    grass_rect.w = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    grass_rect.h = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

if (grass_image == NULL)
    std::cout << "Couldn't load grass_image" << std::endl;

while (!quit && mainEvent -> type != SDL_Quit)
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, grass_image, NULL, &grass_rect);
}
```

I just don't want to have to do that for EVERY image.  So how could I put that into a function?

Thanks!

Comment: If the library doesnt come with its own PNG loader then you would either have to write your own, or use a 3rd party library for loading it. My reading indicates to me that SDL already supports png, http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to add the method that I already use to load PNGs, but it's not in a function.  I'm just looking for a short cut so I don't have to do this (look in the main post) for every single image.

Comment: Are you seriously asking how to write a function in C++?

Answer (score 11):

You should use SDL_Image API, it has one simple function that loads everything:

```
SDL_Surface *IMG_Load(const char *file);
```

More precisely, it loads ICO(Icon)/CUR(Cursor)/BMP, PNM (PPM/PGM/PBM), XPM,
LBM(IFF ILBM), PCX, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TGA, TIFF, and XV thumbnail formats.

It also has individual format functions such as `IMG_isPNG` and `IMG_LoadPNG_RW`.

This lib is one of the most commonly used for image file loading with SDL, I think.

[Website](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) and [Documentation](http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/SDL_image/SDL_image.html)

Comment: An alternative is to use [stb_image.h](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h)

Answer (score 6):

**SDL 2 SDL_image minimal runnable example**

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

int main(void) {
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(
        500, 500,
        0, &window, &renderer
    );
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    texture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "flower.png");
    while (1) {
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) && event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            break;
    }
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/82d70fcf50397e65098453320ba384d660355b61/sdl/png.c).

Compile and run:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev
gcc -std=c99 -o main -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.c -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
./main
```

Outcome:

[image]

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, GCC 6.4.0, SDL 2.0.4, SDL Image 2.0.1.

Comment: Btw, it's easier to use `IMG_LoadTexture()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks! I was grepping the online docs for texture, but it seems to be for the 1.x version for some reason. Updated.

Comment: Downvoters please explain so I can learn and improve info, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In order to load PNG files with SDL you need to have the SDL_Image library extension.

http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image

A description of this library extension:

"SDL_image is an image file loading library. It loads images as SDL surfaces, and supports the following formats: BMP, GIF, JPEG, LBM, PCX, PNG, PNM, TGA, TIFF, WEBP, XCF, XPM, XV."

Comment: YEah, sorry, just updated the main post, that should help things. I know how to load a PNG I'm just looking for a simpler way to do it.